# How can I store possible values of a dropdown-box in a model and use them in a form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to create a dropdown box where a list of possible values is taken from the model, in such a way that when instanciating a model in the admins view for example, multiple options can be given to the model for use as the variables in the dropdown-box.

I have tried googling around and can't find a clear awnser, or I am not understanding them at least. I also found [django-collectionfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-collectionfield/) is this what I need?

Just to be clear, I want the variables displayed to be dynamic on a model level. I want the give the administrator option to define a list of variables which then are used on the appropriate form in a dropdown-box.

Here is a [small code-pen](https://codepen.io/kilianl/pen/dyyRgLQ) with what I want.

```
<form>
  <select name="options">
    <option value="option1">A</option>
    <option value="option2">B</option>
    <option value="option3">C</option>
    <option value="option4">D</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p>I want the option names (A, B, C) and values (option1, option2, option3)
to be confiurable, <br>sometimes there might be 3 values
sometimes 10, I have no control over this.</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give some more info on how these choices are defined? Does the admin set a global list of choices? Is the list of choices defined by some kind of logic? What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: The choices should be define per object. Imagine you are in the django-admin panel, you create a new model and when creating the admin should be able to specify the variables somewhere.

Comment: Do you want to variables be model instances?

Comment: No, just integers in my case. But ofcourse I could probably make instances of the integers and use them but I feel like this should be possible isn't it?